# How to iterate through a nested dictionary with varying depth, and make a copy with value representing the path?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
 {'n11' : 
        {'n12a':
               {'n13a' : 10 , 'n13b' : "some text"},
         'n12b':
                {'n13c' : 
                          {'n14a': 40}
                }
         },
   'n21': 
         {'n22a' : 20 }
 }
```

And I want to iterate through the dictionary until I reach a value which is not a dictionary, and replace it with the "full path" to that value.

```
 {'n11' : 
        {'n12a':
               {'n13a' : 'n11_n12a_n13a' , 'n13b' : 'n11_n12a_n13b'},
         'n12b':
                {'n13c' : 
                          {'n14a': 'n11_n12b_n13c_n14a'}
                }
         },
   'n21': 
         {'n22a' : 'n21_n22a' }
 }
```

I know how to iterate through a nested dictionary with the following function, but I don't understand how to copy the same structure but with the updated value.

```
 def myprint(d,path=[]):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            path.append(k)
            myprint(v,path)
        else:
            print('_'.join(path))

  output:
  'n11_n12a_n13a'
  'n11_n12a_n13b'
  'n11_n12b_n13c_n14a'
  'n21_n22a'
```

But how do I get it into another dictionary?

Comment: With varying depth you should use recursive function to parse the dictionary.

Comment: So the function I provide parses the dictionary recursively, I just am not sure on how to update the value once I hit "bottom" of the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this would be using the same recursive function to not generate excess performance overhead. To copy the dictionary you can use `copy.deepcopy()` and then take that copy through the function, but replace the values instead of just printing the path:

```
import copy


data = {'n11': {'n12a': {'n13a': 10, 'n13b': "some text"}, 'n12b': {'n13c': {'n14a': 40}}}, 'n21': {'n22a': 20}}


def myreplace(d, path=[]):
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        myreplace(v, path + [k])
    else:
        print('_'.join(path + [k]))
        d[k] = '_'.join(path + [k])
return d


copy_of_data = copy.deepcopy(data)
copy_of_data = myreplace(copy_of_data)
print(data)
print(copy_of_data)
```

I had to modify the original function slightly to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to iterate:

```
nested_dict = {'A': {'key_B': 'value_B'},
               'B': {'key_C': 'value_C'},
               'C': {'key_C': {'key_D':'value_D'}}
               }


def loop_nested(dictionary: dict):
  for key in dictionary:
      value = dictionary[key]
      print(key)
      if isinstance(value, dict):
        loop_nested(value)
      else:
       print(value)

    
loop_nested(nested_dict)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ndicts`](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) (I am the author).

```
from ndicts import NestedDict

d = {
    'n11': {
        'n12a': {'n13a' : 10 , 'n13b' : "some text"},
        'n12b': {'n13c': {'n14a': 40}}
    },
    'n21': {'n22a' : 20 }
}

nd = NestedDict(d)
values = ("_".join(k) for k in nd.keys())
result = NestedDict.from_tuples(nd.keys(), values)

dict(result)
# {('n11', 'n12a', 'n13a'): 'n11_n12a_n13a', ('n11', 'n12a', 'n13b'): 'n11_n12a_n13b', ('n11', 'n12b', 'n13c', 'n14a'): 'n11_n12b_n13c_n14a', ('n21', 'n22a'): 'n21_n22a'}
```

Basically `NestedDict` allows you to flatten a nested dictionary using recursion under the hood. Here's what `keys()` does:

```
list(nd.keys())
# [('n11', 'n12a', 'n13a'), ('n11', 'n12a', 'n13b'), ('n11', 'n12b', 'n13c', 'n14a'), ('n21', 'n22a')]
```